# wireguard config missing something on the server

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

Trying to get wireguard vpn test working and I'm stuck. Any suggestions about what to check next would be appreciated.

Server is a DO droplet running Ubuntu with 3.13.0-141 kernel, client is desktop kvm guest running Mint with 4.4.0-112 kernel and bridged network connection behind nat router. The client can ping the server ok but any other packet types seem to get lost, though tcpdump shows lots of packets arriving at wg0 on the server. ip_forward and proxy_arp are enabled on the server as suggested [in this post](https://www.ericlight.com/wireguard-part-two-vpn-routing.html). ufw on the server has the tunnel port open. The server is also running openvpn on other ports.

Using wg-quick with these config files.

Client:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.200
DNS = 8.8.8.8
PrivateKey = UJeiJJvi5NdqiBrgBfsim+ZS4c69M5EP5fUNNIXMy08=
[Peer]
PublicKey = MreTtFUDB5bQfkegxX2cvz3BLC9sybK4y0loTKhVunU=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 159.203.227.235:51820

sudo wg-quick up ./wg0.conf 
[sudo] password for jim: 
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip address add 10.0.0.200 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 dev wg0
[#] ip link set wg0 up
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
```

Server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.201
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = 6GBAE7bFjrOfEp1uWiPvoW+5CyfpjsBmK0/vCIWbGl0=
[Peer]
PublicKey = furwAmh4vbKrLAGZG/QDIUT2a1GLi0WxDY6YdQKzIHE=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.200/32

sudo wg-quick up ./wg0.conf
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 dev wg0
[#] ip link set wg0 up
[#] ip route add 10.0.0.200/32 dev wg0

ip route show table all

default via 159.203.224.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.200 dev wg0  scope link 
10.12.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.0.5 
159.203.224.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 159.203.227.235 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
broadcast 10.12.0.0 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.0.5 
local 10.12.0.5 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.12.0.5 
broadcast 10.12.255.255 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.0.5 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 159.203.224.0 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 159.203.227.235 
local 159.203.227.235 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 159.203.227.235 
broadcast 159.203.239.255 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 159.203.227.235 
broadcast 172.17.0.0 dev docker0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 172.17.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev veth215195c  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev docker0  proto kernel  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
local ::1 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
local fe80::42:2fff:fec9:400 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
local fe80::601:d8ff:febf:4701 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
local fe80::84ce:13ff:feaf:f628 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
ff00::/8 dev eth0  table local  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev veth215195c  table local  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev docker0  table local  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this working with the help of this very useful [blog post](https://www.ckn.io/blog/2017/11/14/wireguard-vpn-typical-setup)
which also covers how to set up a dns server to prevent client
dns traffic from leaking outside the tunnel.

The main problem was incomplete filter/nat setup on the server. 
The post covers the necessary iptables commands. Since ufw was 
already being using for simple things like ssh and I did not want 
to try converting everything to one format I just combined them. 
This worked for a fresh droplet running Ubuntu 16.04. Also tested on 
my original Ubuntu 14.04 system, where I had to add an additional 
ufw rule:

ufw route allow in on wg0 from 10.200.200.2 out on eth0

apparently because for some reason the default policies
for input and forwarding had been set to DROP.

Comment: solved my problem. seems like UFW blocks forwarding by default. would you mind sharing the blog you got this from?